# Multiple paginator with different page number

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.5

I am using `CakePHP 2.5.x`. In single request I am calling `paginate()` method twice. In first call, I do not need `page` parameter as I am selecting all records for that.

For second call of `paginate()`, I am selecting data based on `page` parameter found in URL.

Now, concern is that:

```
http://localhost/xyz/home/get_data/page:1   //working fine
http://localhost/xyz/home/get_data/page:2   //throw 404 from first paginate()
```

What will be good way to omit `page` param for first `paginate()` call.

**P.S.** I am using same `model` for both `paginate()` call.

Point me if it's duplicate. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out way to solve the problem. Here are steps I am following for first `paginate()` call (where the actual issue exist)

1. **I save original `page` param from `url` in another variable**

```
//get original page number from request and set first page manually
$original_page_number = !empty($this->request->params['named']['page']) ? $this->request->params['named']['page'] : 1;
$this->request->params['named']['page'] = 1;
```

2. **Call `paginate()` function**
3. **Reassign original `page` param to `request` object**

```
//set back to original page number
$this->request->params['named']['page'] = $original_page_number;
```

As I have problem in first `paginate()` call, so I omitted `page` param for that call only.

Hope it will help someone!